# Documentation for special variables in ggplot (..count.., ..density.., etc.)

Tags: r, ggplot2

The stats_ functions in ggplot2 create special variables, e.g. `stat_bin2d` creates a special variable called `..count..`. Where can I find documentation listing which special variables are returned by which stat_ function?

I've looked on the main ggplot2 [documentation pages](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/stat_bin2d.html), and in R online help. I tried reading the source code for stat_bin2d, but it uses bits of the language I don't understand --  I don't know how to get at the code behind `StatBin2d$new(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of them are documented in the value section of the help pages, e.g., `?stat_boxplot` says

> Value:
>
> ```
>  A data frame with additional columns:
> ```
>
> width: width of boxplot
>
> ```
> ymin: lower whisker = smallest observation greater than or equal to
>       lower hinge - 1.5 * IQR
> ```
>
> lower: lower hinge, 25% quantile
>
> notchlower: lower edge of notch = median - 1.58 * IQR / sqrt(n)
>
> middle: median, 50% quantile
>
> notchupper: upper edge of notch = median + 1.58 * IQR / sqrt(n)
>
> upper: upper hinge, 75% quantile
>
> ```
> ymax: upper whisker = largest observation less than or equal to
>       upper hinge + 1.5 * IQR
> ```

I suggest submitting bug reports for those that remain undocumented. There is a [bug report](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/132) for `stat_bin2d`, but it was closed as fixed. If you create a new bug report you can refer to that one.