# How to plot expected values and the reference value in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I plot the observed values per place with points and errorbars, which works as expected.

Problems:

1. I try also to plot the *expected* value per place as a short horizontal line, centered in the same way as the points. I use segments for this, the lines appear, however they are not centered and I cannot figure out how to control them.
2. I would like to plot the *reference* value which is the same per year for all the places  but changes from year to year. I get the line with geom_line, but it is oblique and I would like to have steps (or two lines with an interrupt). With geom_steps I get the vertical shift per place,  not per year. I tried the `geom_hline` as well however with defining a data.frame with `hline.data<-data.frame(hy=chunk$Reference.Value, hx=chunk$Year)` a get two parallel lines along the whole plot.

Could you please show me what I am doing wrong?
Thank you very much in advance!

The code with my attempts:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

chunk<-fread("
Year;Places;Code;Name;Reference.Value;Value;Expected.Value;CI
2010;Place5;A12;Indicator;0.079;0.087;0.082;0.00286
2010;Place1;A12;Indicator;0.079;0.075;0.086;0.02317
2010;Place2;A12;Indicator;0.079;0.059;0.069;0.01955
2010;Place3;A12;Indicator;0.079;0.065;0.067;0.02712
2010;Place4;A12;Indicator;0.079;0.091;0.101;0.03211
2011;Place5;A12;Indicator;0.077;0.062;0.058;0.00260
2011;Place1;A12;Indicator;0.077;0.078;0.069;0.01736
2011;Place2;A12;Indicator;0.077;0.029;0.037;0.02821
2011;Place3;A12;Indicator;0.077;0.062;0.059;0.02166
2011;Place4;A12;Indicator;0.077;0.110;0.099;0.06452")

chunk[,`:=` (Year     = as.factor(Year),
               Places   = as.factor(Places),
               Code     = as.factor(Code),
               Name     = as.factor(Name)
)]

limits <- aes(ymax = Value+CI, ymin=Value-CI)
dodge <- position_dodge(width=0.9)

p <- ggplot(chunk, aes(colour=Places, fill=Places, y=Value, x=Year))

p + geom_linerange(limits, position=dodge) +
geom_point(position=dodge, size = 5) +
geom_segment(position=dodge,
           aes(group=Places, 
               y=Expected.Value, yend=Expected.Value, 
               x=as.numeric(Year)-0.01, xend=as.numeric(Year)+0.01)
) +
geom_line(position=dodge, aes(group=Places, y=Reference.Value,x=Year),   color="black")
# geom_step(position=dodge, direction="vh", aes(group=Places,y=Reference.Value,x=Year), color="black")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my interpretation.  You could get the 'dodge' offsets and use those for the beginnings/endings of your line segments.  The `group` in all the geoms will be `Year`, and offests determined by dodge just say how far from that grouping the `Place` factors should be.

```
## Get offsets for dodge
dodgeWidth <- 0.9
nFactors <- length(levels(chunk[,Places]))
chunk[, `:=` (dPlaces = (dodgeWidth/nFactors)*(as.numeric(Places) - mean(as.numeric(Places))))]

limits <- aes(ymax = Value+CI, ymin=Value-CI)
dodge <- position_dodge(width=0.9)
p <- ggplot(chunk, aes(colour=Places, fill=Places, y=Value, x=Year))

p + geom_linerange(limits, position=dodge) +
  geom_point(position=dodge, size = 5) +
  geom_segment(position=dodge, aes(y=Expected.Value, yend=Expected.Value, 
                   x=as.numeric(Year)+dPlaces-0.1, xend=as.numeric(Year)+dPlaces+0.1)) +
  geom_step(aes(group=Year, y=Reference.Value, 
                x=as.numeric(Year)+dPlaces), color="black", linetype=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `geom_errorbar` with `stat = "hline"` much as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4245249/2461552) to get the horizontal lines dodged how you want them.  You would use `geom_errorbar` twice, once for adding the `Expected.Value` lines and once for the `Reference.Value` lines.

```
ggplot(chunk, aes(colour=Places, fill=Places, y=Value, x=Year)) +
    geom_linerange(limits, position=dodge) +
    geom_point(position=dodge, size = 5) +
    geom_errorbar(stat = "hline", aes(yintercept = Expected.Value, ymax = ..y.., ymin = ..y..), 
                position = dodge, width = .8)  +
    geom_errorbar(stat = "hline", aes(group = Year, yintercept = Reference.Value, ymax = ..y.., ymin = ..y..), 
                position = dodge, color="black", width = .8, linetype = 2)
```

[image]

**Edit**

The `stat = "hline"` approach no longer works in the development version of R per this [github issue](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1259).  However, `geom_errorbar` can be used directly to achieve the same result.

```
ggplot(chunk, aes(colour=Places, fill=Places, y=Value, x=Year)) +
    geom_linerange(limits, position=dodge) +
    geom_point(position=dodge, size = 5) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(y = Expected.Value, ymax = ..y.., ymin = ..y..), 
                position = dodge, width = .8)  +
    geom_errorbar(aes(group = Year, y = Reference.Value, ymax = ..y.., ymin = ..y..), 
                position = dodge, color="black", width = .8, linetype = 2)
```

Comment: This is a very interesting option, thank you very much!

Comment: Another question if I dare :-) I understand what  `..y..` means but cannot find a documentation to this. Could you please point me to it? Many thanks!

Comment: @v_e Those special variables are most often in the documentation for the appropriate `stat_*` function (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556069/documentation-for-special-variables-in-ggplot-count-density-etc) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/I9PVlFAAe9U) for some info).  In this case I haven't actually found the documentation, but `..y..` is a short-cut to avoid rewriting the name of the `yintercept` variable when using `geom_errorbar` like this as `ymax` and `ymin` are required aesthetics in `geom_errorbar` but are irrelevant to a horizontal line.

Comment: Thanks again! I could not find this without you.