# Percent labels in barplot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-text

I made the following graph using ggplot2. What I seek is to add labels with percentages to each of the bars.

```
cat.ocup.grafico<-ggplot(subset(casen8va, !is.na(o15)), 
aes(factor(o15), weight=expr))+
geom_bar(aes(y =(..count..)/sum(..count..)), fill="blue")+
ylab("Porcentaje")+xlab("Categoría Ocupacional")+coord_flip()
```

[image: plot1]

To do that I tried with the following code. But for some reason, the bars are erased.

Can someone help me?

```
cat.ocup.grafico+geom_text(aes(label =ifelse((..count..)==0,"",
scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..)))), 
stat="count",colour="darkgreen")
```

[image: plot2]

Comment: can you `dput()` your data.frame so we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: People are more likely to help you if you [write a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5965451#5965451). Columns names like `..count..` are likely to cause a problem. Try renaming this column to `count` before making the plot.

Comment: duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695497/ggplot-showing-instead-of-counts-in-charts-of-categorical-variables/14511974#14511974

Comment: See the Porcentaje axis. First case has the scale between 0 and ~0.7, while on the second, it's between 0 and 50000. The bars are there, just not visible. :)

Comment: @PaulRougieux `..count..` is a special variable in `ggplot2`. Please, see the related questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570293/special-variables-in-ggplot-count-density-etc and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556069/documentation-for-special-variables-in-ggplot-count-density-etc